# How to get all Parent records which doesn't have child record

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework where I want to fetch all the parent records which doesn't have child record.

How to query the same?

Parent Table -> "Messages"
  Child Table  - > "SentMessages"

EDIT: 
Please note: I need th solution in Entity Framework classes.

Currently I am using -

```
ctx.Messages.Where(m => ctx.SentMessages(x => x.msgid != m.msgid))
```

but it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this LINQ,

```
MessageList.Where(m => !SentMessageList.Select(sm => sm.MsgId).Contains(m.MsgId));
```

Comment: how did you got MessageList?

Comment: MessageList is 'Messages' table record list, and SentMessageList is 'SentMessages' table record list, m.MsgId is 'Messages' table primary key, sm.MsgId is foreign key of Messages table in 'SentMessages' table.

Comment: @PareshMakwana you should have writen : `ctx.Messages.Where(m => !ctx.SentMessages.Select(sm => sm.MsgId).Contains(m.MsgId));`

Answer (score 0):

in pseudo code:

```
from m in Messages
where m.Sents.Count() == 0
select m
```